# How to change border color of nav-tab?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm having trouble changing the border color for Tab 2 (see below). For Tab 1, the color changes from the default light gray color.

My custom CSS is placed after the bootstrap 5 CSS so it should be overwriting my changes without issue. What am I doing wrong here?

**CSS**

```
.nav-tabs {
    border-color: black;
}

.nav-tabs > li > a {
   border-color: red;
}

.nav-tabs > li > a:hover {
   border-color: blue;
}

.nav-tabs > li.active > a {
   border-color: green;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs mb-5">
  <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Tab 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Tab 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems...

The `active` class doesn't automatically change using just HTML markup. Use the [Tabs javascript component](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navs-tabs/#javascript-behavior). For example `data-bs-toggle="tab"`...

```
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs mb-5">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#t1" data-bs-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#t2" data-bs-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Secondly, the `active` class goes on the `nav-link` not the `nav-item`. So the CSS selector would be...

```
.nav-tabs > li > .nav-link.active {
   border-color: green;
}
```

https://codeply.com/p/EtmicwumKC

Comment: Ah, this makes a lot of sense. I ended up adding two more CSS styles that go in the <li> so I can manipulate what I wanted to do. Moving the active to the <a> wouldn't work for me.